# JavaFX 2.1 TableView that includes WebView cells

Tags: javafx-2

I want to create a JavaFX table that, in the cells of one column, allows the user to edit XHTML text. I only need very basic formatting capabilities like bold, italic, striketrough.

I have already managed to implement this by using my own subclass of TableCell and using a WebView for each cell (HTMLEditor would of course have been another choice, but my guess is that for my requirements, WebView should be sufficient).

However, to make editing comfortable for the user, I need the following features:
1. The cell height needs to resize if the user enters multi-line text.
2. A context menu (or, if not possible, some other menu or button) should allow formatting parts of the text in a cell as described above (bold, italic..)

Has anybody been successful in implementing something similar ? I have seen suggestions on the web, but they rarely included code samples.

Answer (score 0):

I have succedded doing something similar.
I figured I can share some of the basic clues that allowed me to achieve it.

1. Resize the whole WebView.  For that, the whole WebView must be an editable html page.  You achive that by setting contenteditable to true:

   <body contenteditable='true' id='content'></body>
2. You can have a context menu over a webview.  But it is something tricky, as you must first disable the original context menu associated to it.

   WebView editView;

   ...

   EventDispatcher originalDispatcher = editView.getEventDispatcher();
       editView.setEventDispatcher(new WebmenuEventDispatcher(originalDispatcher));

And this is the event dispatcher class:

```
 public class WebmenuEventDispatcher implements EventDispatcher {

        private EventDispatcher originalDispatcher;

        public WebmenuEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher originalDispatcher) {
            this.originalDispatcher = originalDispatcher;
        }

        @Override
        public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
            if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
                if (MouseButton.SECONDARY == mouseEvent.getButton()) {
                    mouseEvent.consume();
                    // Show our own menu
                    cmEdit.show(editView.getScene().getWindow(), mouseEvent.getScreenX(), mouseEvent.getScreenY());
                }
            }
            return originalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
        }
    }
```

Now, for setting the font from within that menu, you need a bidirectional Java<->javascript bridge  and use some javascript in the webview side.

Comment: Hi betaman. Thank you very much for your comment, I will try your solution. I am still struggling with the "Java <-> javascript bridge" as you call. I know how to execute Javascript and how to access Java from it in principle. But I have still little ideas on how to access the size of the user input in the WebView and resize the WebView accordingly.

Comment: Maybe you can do that from javascript, using:
window.innerWidth  and  window.innerHeight
detect them on every keypress and send them over to your Java app to resize accordingly.   Not sure if it will work, but worth a try.

Comment: You may want to try also:  document.body.clientHeight  and 
document.body.clientWidth.   Tell me if you make it work with any of these.